# Can I fork a forked repo to get access to it, where the original repo is private?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-fork

There is a repo under different organization to which I don't have access. Can any of my friends fork and give me the access? Can I fork the repo, which they forked already?

Is there anther way that I can access the repo? Read-only access would be fine.

To all, Thanks for the comments. I just want to understand If there is any other legal way to quickly access the repo. Wanted to understand the technical feasibility.

Thinking that adding me as a Collaborator takes time, I looked for some quick options. Its better I will ask the Owner.

Yes, I am not going to take the cloned repo from someones machine, who have access. 
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: How about asking the organization to add you as a collaborator with read-only access to the repository? You don't have to be a member of the organization for this to work.

Comment: If there was any such chance, why would I even ask this question  @jdno

Comment: Attempting to gain access to a private repo without the owner's permission is morally dubious. Consider that, if caught, the best case scenario is your friend will probably be fired. Not to mention, depending on the laws in play, you could be prosecuted for anything from copyright infringement to corporate espionage.

Comment: Better, people down-vote by giving a appropriate reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can any of my friends fork and give me the access. Can I fork the repo, which they forked already?

[Not using GitHub's forking feature](https://help.github.com/articles/about-forks/):

> Private forks inherit the permissions structure of the upstream or parent repository. For example, if the upstream repository is private and gives read/write access to a team, then the same team will have read/write access to any forks of the private upstream repository. This helps owners of private repositories maintain control over their code.

I *strongly* advise you not to try to circumvent the access controls on the private repository you wish you access. At the very least it's unethical and you may be breaking laws and contracts. It would be *much* better to request access and honour the answer you receive.

From a purely technical perspective there's nothing stopping a person with a local clone from sharing it (though again this is very likely to break laws, contracts, or both). By doing so you're not just putting yourself at risk, you're putting your friend at risk too.

Just because something *can* be done doesn't mean it *should* be done.